# TFS Submodule in a seperate Team Project

Tags: git, tfs

I am trying to setup a TFS for a small team and this is my first exposure to something like this. I've done a fair amount of reading into this and as far as I can see what I'm trying to do should be possible but I can't seem to get it to work.

The team that I am working for has two major projects that are currently in development but we share the development of about 6 in-house libraries that we have developed. All of this libs are set up as their own git so that we can track them separately from the main project. They are linked into the main project using git submodules.

- Proj_Main1
- Proj_Main2
- Lib_1
- Lib_2
  ...

Lib_1 and Lib_2 are submodules of Proj_Main1 and Proj_Main2.

I have setup each git repo as a separate TFS Project all within one Collection but my main projects won't pull the submodule repos from their respective team projects. I have of course updated the .submodule file with the correct path and urls.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? I think my problem is that my main project repos don't have the permissions to access the other project repos but I don't know how to fix this.

From what I've read generally people would add the libraries as separate Git's inside the Proj_Main1 and Proj_Main2 Projects but doing this doesn't allow me to push updates from one library repo to its matching in the other project.

Any guidance on how to repair this would be appreciated.

---

We are using Tfs2017.Update1 with SQL Server 2016 and we are using Windows Groups to handle permissions.

Answer (score 2):

> I have of course updated the .submodule file with the correct path and urls.

(I suppose you meant the `.gitmodules`)

To see the content of the submodules, you should need a:

```
git submodule update --recursive --init
```

Make sure you don't have a [cached credential issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19246151/6309).

The [OP Aubrey H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7811565/aubrey-h) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643380/tfs-submodule-in-a-seperate-team-project/44644814#comment76564352_44644814):

> I updated the `.gitmodules` file with incorrect links: I put in the address to the TFS project overview page and not the TFS project git page.
>   So, of course, it failed to find anything.

Comment: I ended up fixing this issue and it was a combination of a cached credential issue and my own stupidity. I updated the `.gitmodule` file with incorrect links. I put in the address to the TFS project overview page and not the TFS project git page. So, of course, it failed to find anything.

Comment: @AubreyH. Well spotted! I have included the comment in the answer for more visibility.